# Rewrite rule to change url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to clean my URLs but everything I've tried so far seems to completely give me an 500 internal server error.

What I am trying to achieve is:
`www.site.com/en/?page=contact` to change to: `www.site.com/en/contact`

and also links like this for example:
`www.site.com/en/?page=test&category=tester` to change to: `www.site.com/en/test/tester`

my `.htaccess` is like so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^?page=([-\w]+)$ www.site.com/en/$1 [NC,L]
```

but I've have no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

For your first URL you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /en/?page=$1 [L]
```

it will leave you with the URL: `www.site.com/en/contact`.

Your second rule will need to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /en/?page=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Which will leave you with the URL: `www.site.com/en/test/tester`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: i tried this but it is not working still, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for helping out friend